# Changing texts with fade in, How?

Tags: javascript, html

So my problem is that I know how to change a text, however I don't know how to fade in the new text with a click.

```
<script>
function changeText() {
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = " Newtext";
 document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = " Newtext2";
 }
</script>
<body>
<p id="demo">text</p>
<p id="demo2">text2</P>
<button onclick="changeText()">Change Texts</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  The question as-is is not a good fit.  What have you tried to "fade in"? What resources have you checked / looked at? Questions on StackOverflow are expected to show research effort, and your actual effort _at the question you are asking_.

Comment: You can use the jQuery library to do so.

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery, fadeOut and fadeIn functions work well and have callbacks so you can change the text after fadeout, then fade back in.

```js
function changeText() {
 $("#demo").fadeOut(function() {
   $(this).html(" Newtext");
   $(this).fadeIn();
 });
 $("#demo2").fadeOut(function() {
   $(this).html(" Newtext2");
   $(this).fadeIn();
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="demo">text</p>
<p id="demo2">text2</P>
<button onclick="changeText()">Change Texts</button>
```